# Getting 'Could not find test files' Error when attempting to run TestCafe tests

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to run some TestCafe tests from our build server, but getting the following error...

"Could not find test files at the following location: "C:\Testing\TestCafe".
Check patterns for errors:

tests/my-test.ts

or launch TestCafe from a different directory."

I did have them running or able to be found on this machine previously, but others have taken over the test coding and changed the structure a bit when moving it to a Git repository.  Now when I grab the tests from Git and try to run, the problem presents itself.  I'm not sure if there is something in a config file that needs adjustment but don't know where to start looking.

The intention is to have it part of our CI process, but the problem is also seen when I attempt to run the tests from the command line.  The build process does install TestCafe, but there is something strange around this as well.

When the build failes with the can't find tests error, if I try to run the following command in the proper location...

tescafe chrome tests/my-test.ts

... I get, 'testcafe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Just can't understand why I can't get these tests running.  TestCafe setup was pretty much easy previously.

ADDENDUM:  I've added a screenshot of the working directory where I cd to and run the testcafe command as well as the tests subdirectory containing the test I'm trying to run.

[image: Working Folder]

[image: Tests Folder]

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: If I install TestCafe globally (-g), then I no longer receive the "not recognized" message.  However, it still cannot find the tests!

Comment: What happens if you try the full path to the test file? `testcafe chrome C:\Testing\TestCafe\tests\my-test.ts`? It would be helpful to see your current file structure, as testcafe will look for test files relative to where you execute it from

Comment: The same only the problematic pattern listed is not the full path to the test.ts file.  When other developers took this over, they rearranged things a bit, but here is what I'm working with right now...  \data, \node_modules\, \page_modules, \report, \tests, .testcaferc.json, .tfignore, config.ts, config.ts_template, package.json, package-lock.json.

Comment: The config.ts stuff holds the URL we will be testing against and called from within the tests.  I think it has to do with something in .testcaferc or package*.json files.  The structure should be ok and I am running the tests from the command line in the folder holding this stuff.

Comment: What I can't understand is what is overriding what I use on the command line - either directory relative to the test file or the full path to that file.  Does the package.json or the .testcaferc.json file govern that?

Comment: Pics added and thanks for helping out!!

Comment: If you have a `src` property in the `.testcaferc.json` file, then this is usually what testcafe will use to find your tests, but this is then overridden in the CLI by passing in `tests/my-test.ts`. Rather than using `testcafe xx xxxxx`, I trigger it from the node_modules: `NODE_PATH='./' node ./node_modules/testcafe/bin/testcafe` so that I get around the whole Global vs Local issue

Comment: What if you tried using a Glob pattern? You've said you're triggering this from the parent folder of `tests`, so the only other thought would be to use a relative path of `./tests/my-test.ts`

Comment: Final request - would you be able to add a screenshot of your terminal, just to see what's going on there?

Answer (score 1):

`testcafe chrome tests/my-test.ts` is just a template; it isn't a real path to your tests. This error means that the path that you set in CLI is wrong, and there aren't any tests. You need to:

1. Find out where you start CLI. Please attach a screenshot to your question.
2. Define an absolute path to tests or a path relative to the place where CLI was started. Please share a screenshot of your project tree where the directory with tests is open.

Also, you missed `t` in the `tescafe chrome tests/my-test.ts` command. It should be `tesTcafe chrome tests/my-test.ts`. That is why you get the "'tescafe' is not recognized as an internal or external command" error.

Comment: But if I'm running the tests in the parent folder to tests, shouldn't testcafe chrome tests/my-tests.ts work.  LOL, that command with the typo is understandable, but I do get the not recognized with the correct command as well.  I'm wondering how I should handle the installation of testcafe in general.  I'm wondering if I should just manually install it globally and not have the installation as part of the build process.  The build process was continually installing it locally from or in the \tests parent folder as the working folders are wiped out with each build.

Comment: Also, what does this mean... "Find out where you start CLI. Please attach a screenshot to your question."  Do you mean where I'm running the commands from?  I'm in the \tests parent folder.  As you can probably tell, I'm no expert with TestCafe, just trying to add to CI.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get things working by starting from scratch.  I uninstalled TestCafe and cleaned the working folder.  During next build it was fine.  I'm sure I've tried this several times, but it just started working.

One positive that came out of it was that I discovered a typo in a test file name, which was also causing issues finding the test I was using to check testing setup.

Thanks for helping!!